# CloudFront Distribution Not Serving Specific Routes from S3 Bucket

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I've developed a React application and deployed its created build to an S3 bucket. The application is with various pages such as sign in, signup, and user/*.

**Problem:**
However, after setting up a CloudFront distribution for the S3 bucket (e.g., `https://d4cvljufvoog1.cloudfront.net`), accessing specific routes directly through the CloudFront URL results in an "Access Denied" error. For instance, when navigating to ``https://d4cvljufvoog1.cloudfront.net/signin,

however `https://d4cvljufvoog1.cloudfront.net` that is working but when i hit signin page that is also in build but getting access denied issue also i have added in distribution behavior

**following error is encountered:**

```
<Error>
  <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
  <Message>Access Denied</Message>
  <RequestId>8545M4YXSVV59542</RequestId>
  <HostId>Hj247UsHnGHPCl1yyFRAWPAKDUVtKrSUnHN8mcyQMEzxiKeynWhpzfONp1t0fEKPhO6eM63vY3Q=</HostId>
</Error>
```

**Actions Taken:**
I've configured CloudFront behaviors to match the paths of the application, including /signin, with the same S3 bucket.

**Request for Assistance:**
What steps should I take to troubleshoot and resolve this issue? I need guidance on ensuring CloudFront properly serves all routes from the S3 bucket without encountering access issues from the same bucket

like

```
https://d4cvljufvoog1.cloudfront.net/signin
https://d4cvljufvoog1.cloudfront.net/signup
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with ReactJS application in S3 + CloudFront combination, besides adding a behavior, it's necessary to add `Error pages`. In error pages tab, you should add  error pages for these 2 HTTP codes:

- 403
- 404

For both of these status codes, `HTTP response code` should be set to 200 and `Response page path` should be set to `/index.html`. The reason is that for ReactJS you don't have `signin` or some other files so that's why S3 is returning error. Instead, when you get this error, you redirect it back to `index.html` and that's when React's router takes over and send you to proper page.

Comment: I have resolved this with your help after one day.
Can you help me with on logic, I'm stuck on that point and not getting any solution.
I will be very grateful to you.

Comment: @Spiral what logic do you need help with?

Comment: Thanks, Caldazar for replying to me.
I am facing this issue after solving the 404, and 403 issues
Can you please check this link there I have created an issue

https://serverfault.com/q/1153784/1053069